# How can I access data provided to HTML template from Python flask routing in my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

So I have a python flask application that routes to a site and passes along two lists:

```
def chart():
    labels = ['x', 'y', 'z']
    values = [100, 150, 100]
    return render_template('chart.html',
     labels=labels, values=values)
```

I use `Chart.min.js` and I can then use the lists in rendering a graph in my `chart.html`:

```
{% block body %}
<h1>Test chart</h1>

<canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>

<p id="caption">chart displaying labels n' values</p>

<script type=text/javascript>

    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

    var names = [
        {% for item in labels %}
            "{{ item }}",
        {% endfor %}
    ];

    var numbers = [
        {% for item in values %}
            {{ item }},
        {% endfor %}
    ];

    var chartData = {
        labels: names,
        datasets: [{
          label: 'values',
           data: numbers
        }]
    };

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: chartData
    });

</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Now this works fine and I get a nice pretty graph. 
Then I wanted to put my JavaScript in a seperate file in the static folder for my flask application but I cannot find how I'm supposed to access the lists passed along to `chart.htlm`. I can render a graph just fine if I hardcode some data into the JS file but I can't seem to get the data provided by the python code..

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

// var names = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
// var numbers = [100, 150, 100];

var chartData = {
    labels: names,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'values',
        data: numbers
    }]
};

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: chartData
});
```

I have tried to loop the contents of the lists from my python file into different containers such as `<div>`, `<ol>` and `<ul>`and access those through `document.getElementById("")` among some other attempts, can't really remember them all.

I have tried to find the answer on google but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated and I should mention that I'm new to these coding languages and frameworks so please have some oversight if what I am missing is obvious.

=== NEW WORKING VERSION ===

`chart.html` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        const myChart2 = document.getElementById('ChartOne');
        drawChart(ChartOne, {{ labels| tojson }}, {{ values| tojson }}, ChartType.LINE);

    });

</script>

<div>
    <canvas id="ChartOne" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
    <p id="caption">line chart displaying labels n' values</p>
</div>
```

`script.js`:

```
const ChartType = {
    LINE: "line" // add more variables for more chart options
}

function drawEmployeeChart(ctx, labels, values, chartType) {
    var chartData = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'values',
            data: values,
        }]
    };

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: chartType,
        data: chartData
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've separated your javascript into a new js file, you have to get your variables there.

What you could do is define a javascript function in your .js file that takes two arrays:

```
function render_chart(labels, values)
{
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

    var chartData = {
        labels: names,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'values',
            data: values
        }]
    };

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: chartData
    });
}
```

Then call the function from your `chart.html` page, but you have to convert the variables you pass from Flask to json. To do that do this, using the special `tojson` Jinja2 filters:

```
<script type="text/javascript">render_chart({{ labels|tojson }}, {{ values|tojson }})'></script>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks to alot! 
Right, I understood what you meant :)

This works but I have a follow-up question: I get syntax errors when I implement ```<body onload='render_chart({{ labels|tojson }}, {{ values|tojson }})'>``` that tell me ```Property assignments``` and ```Argument expressions``` are expected. What could be the cause of this?

Further, my ```chart.html``` is extended from my ```index.html``` by ```{{ extends 'index.html }}``` blocks and my ```index.html``` already have a ```body``` tag. Is it possible to use another tag where I can call my JS function?

Comment: @shurda Do you have a script block at the bottom of the html page? In there you could put this: `<script type="text/javascript">render_chart({{ labels|tojson }}, {{ values|tojson }});</script>`

Comment: Yes I have a script block, tried your solution and it worked fine.
Modified it further to be more generic. Posting the extended version for people to see.

Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks! And thank you for the help, I really appreciate it :)